# Further confusion with imports in Python

Tags: python, import, namespaces

I can't understand why the following runs (Python 2.7) when one of the modules isn't imported as far as I understand

```
# \sound\formats\script.py
import formats.wavread

print formats.wavread.foo()
print formats.wavwrite.boo()
```

My directory structure is

```
sound\
    __init__.py
    formats\
       __init__.py
        script.py
        wavread.py
        wavwrite.py
```

Both `__init__.py` are empty. The rest have the following code

```
# \sound\formats\wavread.py
import wavwrite # <-- unused import

def foo():
    return "read foo"
```

```
# \sound\formats\wavwrite.py
def boo():
    return "write boo"
```

`script.py` runs fine despite the fact that module `wavwrite.py` is not imported in my understanding. I guess however that somehow it was imported when `import formats.wavread` statement was executed because there is an `import wavwrite` line in the `wavread.py` module. I was under the impression that this import, `import wavwrite`, was totally useless, nevertheless it would make a binding to the `wavread` module's global namespace. Therefore the `wavwrite.boo()` method would be out of scope and inaccessible from inside `script.py`. Apparently it doesn't work like that.

Removing the subpackage prefix from the code of the `script.py` module looks to make the program work as I would expect. Hence if you run the following

```
#\sound\formats\script.py
import wavread

print wavread.foo()
print wavwrite.boo()
```

will execute the `wavread.foo()` method by printing out read foo and will hit an error at the next line where it drops a message `NameError: name 'wavwrite' is not defined` because as expected the `wavwrite` module has not been imported.

What exactly is happening here and how `import formats.wavread` is different to `import wavread` please?

Answer (score 1):

The simple case of `import wavread` is working because your script is in the same directory as `wavread.py`, and so it's importing just that file. If your script was in a different directory it wouldn't be able to find `wavread.py`

The next case, let's see what we can work out. Your directory structure is similar to that in the [Python module tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), so let's use the `dir()` built-in mentioned there, which will show you the contents of a scope. For example:

```
>>> import formats.wavread
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'formats']

# ... new session

>>> from formats import wavread
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'wavread']
```

So we can see that `import formats.wavread` also imports the parent namespaces, as we have `formats` in there. In the second example we are loading only a specific submodule, and so that gets added to our namespace directly, instead of `formats`. A quick test for this is to add a print statement to `formats/__init__.py` - when you then run `import formats.wavread`, that will get printed out:

```
$ cat formats/__init__.py
print("formats __init__.py")
$ python -m formats.wavread -c ""
formats __init__.py
```

Since `formats` as been imported, `formats.wavwrite` and `formats.wavread` are both available.

Now, I'm working this out as I go, so I won't be able to tell you why it was designed this way, this is just what I can tell from the tools available.

Answer (score 1):

When importing a submodule, you also get the submodule's parent module.

Easy example:

```
>>> numpy
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
>>> import numpy.random
>>> numpy
<module 'numpy' from '...\numpy\__init__.pyc'>
```